# How to call a C++ dynamic library from Rust?

Tags: c++, rust, ffi

I want to call a C++ dynamic library (*.so) from Rust, but I don't want to build it from Rust. Like this,

```
cc::Build::new()
    .file("src/foo.cc")
    .shared_flag(true)
    .compile("libfoo.so");
```

In some cases, I only need to call several functions, not all the functions. How can I use it?

Comment: Look at [libloading](https://github.com/nagisa/rust_libloading) but your question is not clear, "I only need to call several functions, not all the functions." this simple don't make sense, you can't "load only one function", you can load all or nothing. A lib is one entity, not just a list of function. Plus, a dynamic lib is a very unstable thing, even used only in C++, you will have trouble to use it dynamically. And I said "dynamically". Link a shared/static library or load a dynamic library are two different concepts, please be more clear

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Before you go further, make sure you have a basic idea of Rust [FFI (foreign function interface)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html).

In Rust, it's easy to call C, but hard to call C++.

To call C functions in Rust, you just have to wrap them with `extern`, do some basic type casting and sometimes `unsafe`.

To call C++ functions, since Rust does not have built-in knowledge of C++ features, you may have to do a lot of manual translation. For example, here is part of the documentation from [Rust-Qt](https://github.com/rust-qt/cpp_to_rust/blob/221feeed079cdf027e197a0cbe783849e33be0a7/cpp_to_rust/cpp_to_rust_generator/README.md):

> Many things are directly translated from C++ to Rust:
>
> - Primitive types are mapped to Rust's primitive types (like `bool`) and types provided by libc crate (like `libc::c_int`).
> - Fixed-size numeric types (e.g `int8_t` or `qint8`) are mapped to Rust's fixed size types (e.g. `i8`).
> - Pointers, references and values are mapped to Rust's respective types.
> - C++ namespaces are mapped to Rust submodules.
> - C++ classes and structs are mapped to Rust structs. This also applies to all instantiations of template classes encountered in the
>   library's API, including template classes of dependencies.
> - Free functions are mapped to free functions.
> - Class methods are mapped to structs' implementations.
> - Destructors are mapped to `Drop` and `CppDeletable` implementations.
> - Function pointer types are mapped to Rust's equivalent representation. Function pointers with references or class values are
>   not supported.
> - `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` are available in Rust through corresponding traits.
>
> Names of Rust identifiers are modified according to Rust's naming
> conventions.
>
> When direct translation is not possible:
>
> - Contents of each include file of the C++ library are placed into a separate submodule.
> - Method overloading is emulated with wrapping arguments in a tuple and creating a trait describing tuples acceptable by each method.
>   Methods with default arguments are treated in the same way.
> - Single inheritance is translated to `Deref` and `DerefMut` implementation, allowing to call base class methods on derived
>   objects. When deref coercions are not enough, `static_cast` should be
>   used to convert from derived to base class.
> - Getter and setter methods are created for each public class field.
>
> Not implemented yet but planned:
>
> - Translate C++ `typedef`s to Rust type aliases.
> - Implement operator traits for structs based on C++ operator methods ([issue](https://github.com/rust-qt/cpp_to_rust/issues/27)). Operators
>   are currently exposed as regular functions with `op_` prefix.
> - Implement Debug and Display traits for structs if applicable methods exist on C++ side.
> - Implement iterator traits for collections.
> - Subclassing API ([issue](https://github.com/rust-qt/cpp_to_rust/issues/26)).
> - Provide access to a class's public variables ([issue](https://github.com/rust-qt/cpp_to_rust/issues/18)).
> - Provide conversion from enums to int and back (used in Qt API).
> - Support C++ types nested into template types, like `Class1<T>::Class2`.
>
> Not planned to support:
>
> - Advanced template usage, like types with integer template arguments.
> - Template partial specializations.
> - Template methods and functions.

My suggestion is to wrap your C++ library as a C library, then call it the official FFI way, or use [rust-bindgen](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-bindgen) to automatically do the wrapping.

If you still want to call C++ in Rust, [rustcxx](https://github.com/google/rustcxx) seems like a handy tool.

As to the library linking, it's pretty simple:

- Put the library into your system library searching paths like `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib/`, make sure it can be found by `ldconfig -p`.
- Or use the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to specify the path where your library lays when you run `cargo` from the CLI.

Answer (score 9):

According to [Rust's official website](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nomicon/ffi.html), there is no official support for linkage with C++. Instead you can try and use C libraries.

There is also a thread on this issue in their [users forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/any-updates-on-calling-c-from-rust/10257), where users suggest some 3rd party projects aiming to tackle this issue:

- [**bindgen**](https://github.com/servo/rust-bindgen) - Auto generation of FFI for Rust
- [**cpp-to-rust**](https://github.com/rust-qt/cpp_to_rust) - Allows to use C++ libraries from Rust. The main target of this project is Qt.

I didn't use them, so I can't recommend anything particular or share my experience, but good luck :)

Answer (score 7):

I feel it's worth mentioning as of now there is CXX library in crate

https://docs.rs/cxx/latest/cxx/

https://cxx.rs/

This is what I will be using going forward in order to interoperate with a C++ Library from a vendor.

The assigned answer has a link but it's publicly archived and all active work is likely here :

https://github.com/dtolnay/cxx