# Can I use Eigen3 from Rust?

Tags: c++, rust, eigen, eigen3

I would like to use Rust to perform linear algebra and tensor operations. So I would like to use Eigen3, which is a C++ library, from Rust by wrapping it with Rust.

I was able to find a way to compile C and C++ files from Rust at the same time as Cargo, but I don't know how to bring the library as is.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52940455/1695172) answer it?

Comment: Eigen is a C++ template library. Those are notoriously difficult to use from other languages. You'd need a C interface, that exposes only a subset of types.

Comment: @mcarton thank you for your comment! Does any documentation exist anywhere about C interfaces that regret the subset of types?

Comment: nominated as dupe: [How to call a C++ dynamic library from Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923460/how-to-call-a-c-dynamic-library-from-rust)