# use a dylib & header files in rust missing fstream

Tags: rust, ffi, dylib, rust-bindgen

I want to use the ctranslate2 library in rust. To use it it needs to be compiled. The result is a dylib file and the includes. How can I use this code?. I found bindgen which makes this possible, but i get this error.

```
 /usr/local/include/ctranslate2/translator.h:3:10: fatal error: 'fstream' file not found
  thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to generate bindings: ClangDiagnostic("/usr/local/include/ctranslate2/translator.h:3:10: fatal error: 'fstream' file not found\n")', build.rs:31:10
```

```rs
extern crate bindgen;

use std::env;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
    // Tell cargo to look for shared libraries in the specified directory
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=/usr/local/lib");

    // Tell cargo to tell rustc to link the system bzip2
    // shared library.
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=ctranslate2");

    // Tell cargo to invalidate the built crate whenever the wrapper changes
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=wrapper.h");

    // The bindgen::Builder is the main entry point
    // to bindgen, and lets you build up options for
    // the resulting bindings.
    let bindings = bindgen::Builder::default()
        // The input header we would like to generate
        // bindings for.
        .header("/usr/local/include/ctranslate2/translator.h")
        // Tell cargo to invalidate the built crate whenever any of the
        // included header files changed.
        .parse_callbacks(Box::new(bindgen::CargoCallbacks))
        // Finish the builder and generate the bindings.
        .generate()
        // Unwrap the Result and panic on failure.
        .expect("Unable to generate bindings");

    // Write the bindings to the $OUT_DIR/bindings.rs file.
    let out_path = PathBuf::from(env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap());
    bindings
        .write_to_file(out_path.join("bindings.rs"))
        .expect("Couldn't write bindings!");
}
``
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923460/how-to-call-a-c-dynamic-library-from-rust

Comment: no, can you explain why fstream is missing? Its a default c++ header file so i thought it must be automaticly mapped, but it seems like its not. I also tried println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=fstream");

Comment: TLDR the duplicates, you can't call C++ from Rust, you need to make a C++ wrapper that exports the functions you want to call as `extern "C"` then call those functions.

Comment: @Jmb its already compiled, so opening it with bindgen should be fine. Also even when i wrap it in c a missing file is a missing file.

Comment: `bindgen` reads the header files, not the compiled files, and it _can't read C++ header files,_ period.